# Dynamic subtraction in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

Please have a look at my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K5Btg5fFS590G7vZsFiepY-2VTPhzJIlkKK_o-9Ag7E/edit?usp=sharing

How do I get:

- C2 to show `Start weight` (i.e. "100,0")
- C3 to show C2 - `Daily weightloss` (i.e. "99,7701")
- C4 to show C3 - `Daily weightloss` (i.e. "99,5402)
- C5 to show C4 - `Daily weightloss` (i.e. "99,3103")
- ...and so on.

The challenge is obviously to do this dynamically since all the user-submitted data, and consequently, all the calculated data might change.

I think this can/should be solved with ArrayFormula somehow but I don't know how.

Comment: Basically 100-row(...)*.5714 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A;
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(A1:A)))<=
       TRANSPOSE( ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(A1:A)))))*
      {B2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(J5*-1&"♦"; COUNTA(A3:A)); "♦"))}); 
 SIGN({B2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(J5*-1&"♦"; COUNTA(A3:A)); "♦"))})^2); IFERROR(1/0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It worked lika a charm, thank you very much! I really appreciate it!

Since you're really good at Google spreadsheeats, could you please have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541965/auto-populate-every-second-day-between-two-given-dates

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you could do this

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",100-(row(A2:A)-row())*J5))
```

although it's not dynamic in the sense of calculating from the previous row.