# Auto-populate every second day between two given dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, array-formulas, auto-populate

I'm currently using the formula in [this article](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/auto-populate-dates-between-two-given-dates-in-google-sheets/) to auto-populate a column of dates between to given dates:

```
=ArrayFormula(TO_DATE(row(indirect("A"&A2):indirect("A"&B2))))
```

How can I tweak the formula to give every **second** date? Column D in the article would then say:

- 01/04/2018
- 03/04/2018
- 05/04/2018
- 07/04/2018 ...and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like the formula skips a day if the start date is an odd date. Can this be corrected?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))),
 MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2)))))), 2)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))),
                 MOD(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))), 2)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! It seems like the formula skips a day if the start date is an odd date. Can this be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))),
               ISODD(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))))))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))),
              ISEVEN(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))))))
```

[image: 0]