# Fill a column of every other date between to given dates in Google Sheets

Tags: date, dynamic, google-sheets, auto-populate

How can I have a column dynamically list every other date between a start date and an end date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is pretty much universal solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))),
 MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2)))))), 2)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

for odd dates use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))),
               ISODD(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))))))
```

for even dates use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))),
              ISEVEN(TO_DATE(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2):INDIRECT("B"&B2))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! I think the formulas are mixed up, but they work fine! Is it possible to have generic formula, so that the first day is always the start date, regardless if it's an odd or an even date? Like, if you changed A2 in your example to 08/04/2019, A10 would be 08/04/2019, A11 10/04/2019 and so on.

Comment: Also, this of course had your formula in my previous question stop working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526175/dynamic-subtraction-in-google-spreadsheet. Is it possible to adjust that formula so it works now when only every other day is listed?

Comment: how are they exactly mixed up?

Comment: The formula for even dates gives odd dates and vice versa, but maybe I misunderstood. I does not matter. The formula in the question I linked to in the comment above still work, but the prerequisites have changed since column A now only contains half the amount of dates. I'm combining your formulas but they don't work together anymore.

Comment: Do you want me to share the document with you so you can see what I'm talking about?

Comment: you can do so, but it's kinda offtopic to this question on which appropriate solution was already provided and yet not accepted (does it mean it not working for you I wonder...)

Comment: Sorry! I have accepted your answer now. The formula works perfectly. Here's a copy of the spreadsheet I'm using the formula in: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19FtnBGUJ9X8oT1vUGDF2JoLEfO9sim-ZTo_Eu5QKa-w/edit?usp=sharing. It's in A2. As you can se I'm using another of your formulas in B2. That formula does not work in combination with the formula in A2 anymore, since column A contains half the amount of dates now. Right now, B42 should contain the end weight (87,0 kg).

Comment: @RawlandHustle well, if you use every 2nd day than J4 increment for running total needs to be doubled too. check your sheet... fx: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A;  
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(A1:A)))<=        
       TRANSPOSE( ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(A1:A)))))*      
      {C2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT((2*J4)*-1&"♦"; COUNTA(A3:A)); "♦"))});   
 SIGN({C2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT((2*J4)*-1&"♦"; COUNTA(A3:A)); "♦"))})^2); IFERROR(1/0)))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191469/discussion-between-player0-and-rawland-hustle).